# whats the worst thing an Android malware is capable of doing?

Tags: malware, android

An android malware can do a lot of damage, whats the absolute worst thing it can do ?
Consider a layman's Android device which is not rooted.

Comment: What systems do two factor authentication with that device? I have seen banking pay systems that send an SMS to the phone, and a malware could read the validation SMS... So a targeted malware that charges money and intercepts the banking SMS could be painful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic "worst". For some this might be that the device is permanently broken so they need to replace it (costs), for others it might be the loss of information on the device (value of data). For some the worst might be that sensitive information leak from the device, like access credentials or sensitive pictures etc and then get used later against the owner or for impersonation. And for others it might be that the device listens to all what their communication and transfers these to the adversary (espionage).

A potent Android malware could do all of this, especially if it can use some bugs to get root access (there were several of these in the past).

Comment: True, for someone worse might be that contacts are stolen. I just wanted to see opinions from people so that I get more insight into dangerous things that people might have seen.

Comment: @skep: You did not ask for attacks seen in the wild but for attacks possible. You also did not ask for opinions - which would be off-topic anyway. But I think I've  read about any of the possible attacks I've mentioned actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume there are no privilege escalation vulnerabilities in Android, apps are generally limited by what permissions you grant them. So, with respective permissions granted, an app could track your location (on modern Android, can be disallowed when the app is not in foreground), scrape your contacts list, take pictures of you, read your files off the SD card, and whatever other permissions are given. However, apps generally can't read files from other apps (if they use their private storage) or spy on your activities outside the app unless you grant them extra permissions (e.g. accessibility service or device admin privileges).

Like @Steffen says, the *real* worst case would be if there is a vulnerability in the Android OS that allows the app to escalate privileges to root.

Comment: Whats possible when an app gets root privilege ? all bets are off ?

Comment: @skep yes, it would have complete control over all apps and data.